# Constructing images using HTML markup?

Tags: html

how to create this code to html code

> `{"title":"my title","url":"http:http://mylink.com","adimage":"http:myimagelink/myimage.jpg","text":"Create html code, Optout: imagelink.com, image by: imagelink","current_time":"2015-01-02 11:59:59","delivery_time":"2015-01-02 11:59:59","linkimage":090,"header":"Browser"}`

Comment: `<pre>{"title":"my title","url":"http:http://mylink.com","adimage":"http:myimagelink/myimage.jpg","text":"Create html code, Optout: imagelink.com, image by: imagelink","current_time":"2015-01-02 11:59:59","delivery_time":"2015-01-02 11:59:59","linkimage":090,"header":"Browser"}</pre>` done.

Comment: `<pre>$your_json_here</pre>`. There. Now it's html.

Comment: the title says: "Constructing images using HTML" and you posted a peace of json, you need to be more specific...

Answer (score -1):

```
<pre style='color:#000000;background:#ffffff;'><html><body style='color:#000000; background:#ffffff; '><pre>
<span style='color:#696969; '>{"title":"my title","url":"http:</span><span style='color:#5555dd; '>http://mylink.com</span><span style='color:#696969; '>","adimage":"http:myimagelink/myimage.jpg","text":"Create html code, Optout: imagelink.com, image by: imagelink","current_time":"2015-01-02 11:59:59","delivery_time":"2015-01-02 11:59:59","linkimage":090,"header":"Browser"}</span>
</pre>
```

Since you didn't state what the original code is (ex. C, C++, Java) this is the best i could do by what i could understand from the given code. i hope this works for you and helps you at all.